# Does my Promise implementation agree with specifications?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a Typescript promise implementation (actually a polyfill) that agrees with current specifications (I used these http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/ ).

It should be done, code is here https://gist.github.com/ilmattodel93/dbefa9eb86715f76e10e ,  but I can't understand the 2.2.7 subpoints of the specs. Only race and all static methods should be missing.

Please someone can explain me the 2.2.7 subpoints and tell me if I have implemented them correctly?

Thanks for attention and time,
Mattia.

Comment: Why not run the test suite?

Comment: From quick glance over the code there is at least 2 bugs: Your `.then()` returns `this` (this is actually not only a bug but misses the whole point of promises) and you don't have a try catch around `x.then`. Run the test suite from https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-tests.

Comment: I tried for hours and hours to use the test suite to test my implementantion, I rewrote it but no way, still fails a lot of tests regarding the then method with objects. This is the new code: https://gist.github.com/ilmattodel93/dbefa9eb86715f76e10e/082cd93623e061727df728a9993e4f24caf24597 Still failing a lot of tests :/ Why? I have implemented code as specs says... i think. :/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review.

Answer (score 2):

Let's let the code do the talking. Lets say we have a promise called `promise1`. According to the spec:

**From Spec**

> then must return a promise

self explainatory:

```
promise2 = promise1.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
```

**From Spec**

> If either onFulfilled or onRejected returns a value x, run the Promise Resolution Procedure [[Resolve]](promise2, x).

If we have

```
promise2 = promise1.then(()=>123,()=>123);
```

Then you can do

```
promise2.then((x)=> /* x should be 123 */, (x)=> /* will not be called */);
```

**From Spec**

> If either onFulfilled or onRejected throws an exception e, promise2 must be rejected with e as the reason.

If we have

```
promise2 = promise1.then(()=> { throw new Error('message'); }, ()=> { throw new Error('message'); });
```

Then you can do

```
promise2.then((x)=> /* should not be called */, (x)=> /* x will be equal to "new Error('message')" */);
```

**From Spec**

> If onFulfilled is not a function and promise1 is fulfilled, promise2 must be fulfilled with the same value.

if we have

```
promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) { resolve(123) });
promise2 = promise1.then(null,null);
```

Then we can do

```
promise2.then((x)=> /* x should be 123 */, (x)=> /* should not be called */);
```

**From Spec**

> If onRejected is not a function and promise1 is rejected, promise2 must be rejected with the same reason.

if we have

```
promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) { reject(123) });
promise2 = promise1.then(null,null);
```

Then we can do

```
promise2.then((x)=> /* should not be called */, (x)=> /* x should be 123 */);
```

To verify that you implementation write tests as shown. I recommend using Mocha with Chai.

Comment: Even after implementing this, promise dont pass the test :/

Answer (score 0):

You can also check your TypeScript definition to compatibility with spec's promises/A+ definition. Here is the TypeScript code for spec's promise: [DefinitelyTyped on GitHub](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/promises-a-plus/promises-a-plus.d.ts).